# I want to filter my data using the reactive function in Shiny. But I am not getting any output

Tags: shiny, dplyr, shiny-reactivity

I am trying filter my data using the dplyr package inside the reactive function in Shiny, but nothing is being displayed in the output. The data is supposed to be filtered by levels of the variable "Country".

Here is the code I have used and the dataframe

```
 datos<-data.frame(time=c(rep(c(2001, 2002),3)), values=c(100,200,300,600,700,800), country=c(rep("Uruguay",2),rep("France",2),rep("United States",2)))

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(inputId ="pais", label="Choose a country", 
  choices =levels(datos$country), selected = "Uruguay"), 
  plotOutput(outputId ="barplot")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  datos3 <- reactive({
    datos%>%
      filter(country=="input$pais")
   })

  output$barplot<-renderPlot({
    ggplot(datos3(),aes(x=time,y=values))+geom_bar(stat="Identity")
  })   
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I am supposed to obtain the values for the selected country, by time period.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't need the quotation marks on "input$pais".

Here is the code with that and the extra `+` in the ggplot section removed.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

datos<-data.frame(time=c(rep(c(2001, 2002),3)), values=c(100,200,300,600,700,800), country=c(rep("Uruguay",2),rep("France",2),rep("United States",2)))

ui <- fluidPage(
    selectInput(inputId ="pais", label="Choose a country", 
                choices =levels(datos$country), selected = "Uruguay"), 
    plotOutput(outputId ="barplot")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    datos3 <- reactive({
        datos%>%
            filter(country==input$pais) #this bit has been changed
    })

    output$barplot<-renderPlot({
        ggplot(datos3(),aes(x=time,y=values))+geom_bar(stat="Identity")
    })   
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```